# binding two csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking for a method to merge two csv files with one shared column (col1):

CSV A:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,b,c,d
e,N/A,g,h
```

CSV B:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,N/A,N/A,d
e,f,N/A,h
```

The desired output is:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

Comment: Hint : Read both csv files into dataframes, join the dataframes, write the joint dataframe into a new csv file.

Comment: have you looked in to the `pandas` module yet?

Comment: load them as dicts then concatenate the contents of the keys :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your CSV A opened as `f1`, CSV B opened as `f2`, and output CSV file opened as `f`, you can zip the `csv.reader` generators constructed from `f1` and `f2` to iterate through the rows in tandem, and zip the rows from the two readers in a generator expression to output the columns that aren't `N/A`:

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(f)
for r1, r2 in zip(csv.reader(f1), csv.reader(f2)):
    w.writerow((c2 if c1 == 'N/A' else c1 for c1, c2 in zip(r1, r2)))
```